# Почему gameobject не null после удаления?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю игру - бесконечный раннер с видом сбоку. Платформы, по которым бежит игрок, движутся влево и когда касаются объекта где-то за экраном, то платформа, которая коснулась его, уничтожается, после чего создаётся новая.
Всего есть 2 платформы (в коде platform1 и platform2), которые идут друг за другом соответственно, когда срабатывает OnTriggerEnter на объекте Destroyer (который за экраном), то платформа уничтожается (по идее platform1 становится null), и я ожидаю срабатывания условия, после чего platform1 начинает ссылаться на platform2, а platform2 в свою очередь становится новым объектом.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject prefabPlatform;
[SerializeField] GameObject platform1;
[SerializeField] GameObject platform2;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Destroy(other.gameObject);

    if (platform1 == null)
    {
        platform1 = platform2;
        platform2 = Instantiate(prefabPlatform, platform1.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 4.8f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

OnTriggerEnter срабатывает, объекты, коснувшиеся его уничтожаются, но почему-то не срабатывает условие, хотя в Inspector'е platform1 считается Missing (GameObject) (рис. 1).

[image: Рис. 1]

Вставлял это условие в FixedUpdate и Update, всё работает.
Подскажите, где почитать об этом или что сделать.

Comment: Объект не уничтожается ровно в том кадре, в котором ты вызвал Destroy. Тебе здесь не нужна проверка на нулл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение становиться null после удаления, в инспекторе отображается Missing, потому что это поле с ссылкой, и ссылка пропала (Missing), Вы уничтожаете объект (хотя стоит завести туда проверку, чтобы не уничтожать наверное все коллайдеры вошедшие в триггер), но он не успел обработать это, но это гарантирует удаление, выполняйте действие дальше

И чтобы избежать ошибок не используйте ссылку на объект который собираетесь удалить в виде `platform.transform` из вашего кода. Сохраните значение до начало его удаления

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.GetComponent<Platform>()) // Необходима проверка что в триггер вошёл именно платформа, для этого используйте что нибудь характерное для вашей платформы, я указал пример
    {
        Vector3 oldPlatformPosition = platform1.transform.position;

        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        platform1 = Instantiate(prefabPlatform, oldPlatformPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 4.8f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```